# How to update total price of products on React functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a e-commerce website. But i'm unable to update the total price using the useState hook of react.

When is use forEach to update total price it give me this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

> codes:

```js
import { Container, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../../../hooks/useAuth";
import Cart from "../Cart/Cart";
import CartProduct from "../CartProduct/CartProduct";

const CartContainer = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  // useNavigate hook
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  /* states */
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const handleAddQuantity = () => {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1);
  };
  const handleRemoveQuantity = () => {
    if (quantity === 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      setQuantity(quantity - 1);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    fetch(`https://limitless-crag-38673.herokuapp.com/cart?id=${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.deletedCount > 0 && setIsDeleted(true);
        alert("successfully deleted");
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsDeleted(false);
    fetch(
      `https://limitless-crag-38673.herokuapp.com/cart/product?email=${user.email}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setProducts(data));
  }, [isDeleted]);
  return (
    <>
      {/* main cart */}
      <Container sx={{ my: 3 }} maxWidth="xl">
        <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 1, md: 2 }}>
          {/* products */}
          <Grid item md={8} xs={12}>
            {/* cart title */}
            <Grid
              container
              sx={{
                borderBottom: "1px solid gray",
                display: { xs: "none", sm: "flex" },
              }}
            >
              <Grid item md={6}>
                <Typography variant="h5">Product</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={4}>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  Price
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              {/* <Grid item md={2}>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  Quantity
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={2}>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  Subtotal
                </Typography>
              </Grid> */}
              <Grid item md={2}>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  Cancel
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            {/*============
           product
           ============= */}

            {products.map((product) => (
              <CartProduct
                key={product._id}
                product={product}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                total={total}
                setTotal={setTotal}
              />
            ))}
          </Grid>

          {/*=========== 
          cart
          ================ */}
          <Cart />
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default CartContainer;
```

`And when I try this it gives me this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

> codes:

```js
import CancelOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CancelOutlined";
import { Grid, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import React from "react";

const CartProduct = ({ product, handleDelete, setTotal, total }) => {
  const { name, price, src } = product;
  setTotal(total + price);

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      sx={{
        borderBottom: "1px solid gray",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: { xs: "column", md: "row" },
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
      spacing={{ md: 2, xs: 1 }}
    >
      {/* product */}
      <Grid
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexDirection: { md: "row", xs: "column" },
        }}
        item
        md={6}
        xs={12}
      >
        <Box>
          <img src={src} alt="" />
        </Box>
        <Typography sx={{ ml: 1 }} variant="h6">
          {name}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      {/* Price */}
      <Grid
        item
        md={4}
        sx={{
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          display: "flex",
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h5">$ {price}</Typography>
      </Grid>
      {/* 
                //  quantity
                <Grid
                  sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                  }}
                  item
                  md={2}
                  xs={12}
                >
                  <IconButton onClick={handleRemoveQuantity}>
                    <RemoveCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <TextField value={quantity} />
                  <IconButton onClick={handleAddQuantity}>
                    <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Grid>
                // Subtotal
                <Grid
                  item
                  md={2}
                  xs={12}
                  sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <Typography variant="h5">$ {product.price}</Typography>
                </Grid> */}
      {/* Cancel */}

      <Grid
        item
        md={2}
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(product._id)}>
          <CancelOutlinedIcon fontSize="large" />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default CartProduct;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not calculate `Total` in parent component?
because setState automatically triggers re-render and in your case every rerender you trigger another setState.

if you want to store data somewhere without re-render use `useRef`.
But in your case i would suggest to set Total price in CartContainer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `total` and `subTotal`, you can directly calculate it from product.

The below code need to be in `CartProduct` as you want to apply delete on individual items.

`const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);`

```
   useEffect(() => {
    setIsDeleted(false);
    fetch(
      `https://limitless-crag-38673.herokuapp.com/cart/product?email=${user.email}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setProducts(data));
  }, [isDeleted]);
```